# Complete .click() function before running another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a function that finds link tags and call click function on each link. I want to call another function(SecondFunction) after click function has been completed. But 2nd function gets called before click function is completed. I want 2nd function to be called after a link has been clicked so function is called on that next clicked page.

```
setInterval(function(){
            $TabLinks= Get all links

            $TabLinks.each(function(index, value){       
                $(this).click(); // Do not worry about syntax, Click on first link(tab), then after clicking on tab,
 I want SecondFunction() to be called
                LinkClicked = 1
                SecondFunction() // This function should be called when it is on clicked page.
},1500)

 function SecondFunction(){
do bunch of other clicking.
setInterval(function(){
},1000)
}
```

Right now, it goes to first function, goes to click function but it does not go to next tab which means click function is not finished. Before going to next tab, it goes to SecondFunction() function and start running that function before click() function is finished.

Comment: Why can't you call the `SecondFunction()` within the `click()` of this element.

Comment: That won't work, As my question says, I want click() to take me next tab where I want to call SecondFunction, not on the click() function.

Comment: you mean that `SecondFunction` runs before the click function is completed?its strange,what is the code of the click function?,make sure it isnot asynchronous

Comment: @lx1412, There is no code for click() function. It just calls jquery click function to click on the <a> tag

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I believe the way javascript's event flow works is you could wrap  SecondFunction() in a timeout of 0 like:

```
 setTimeout(secondFunction,0);
```

Even though the timeout is 0, javascript queues the event to start after the current event flow is finished.

I'll test and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function () { $(this).click(); }, 0);
```

Comment: Are you saying to call this function and then secondFunction()? @lx1412

Comment: I do not want it to run at the same time. I want first click function to be finished and then execute the second function.